# Installing GDAL with ODA on Windows 10

Tags: gdal, dgn

I'm attempting to convert a dgn file (made in microstation v8) to something more modern, that QGIS can read. I've installed GDAL according to [this](https://sandbox.idre.ucla.edu/sandbox/tutorials/installing-gdal-for-windows) tutorial. Appearently, as I know understand it, I need to install the [Open Design Alliance](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/oda.html) Teigha Library.

How do I do this on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

@enor may I give you an advice regarding ODA. If you don't have a special automation requirement I would spend the money into SAFE **FME** Desktop to convert or export the DGN files. FME Desktop has all the necessary Readers and Writers to solve the task and is much more easy to handle. I know what I'm talking about because I'm using both for a long time.

Depending on your goal, whether you like to show the drawings in QGIS or extract parts of it, I would recommend another route if you are in the lucky position to held a Microstation license. I would create vector GeoPDFs (with layers included) that you can directly import into QGIS as raster layers via drag&drop. With the DOS environment variable GDAL_PDF_LAYERS, you can import only specific layers. QGIS 3.26 is even able to import vector layers from the PDF directly via drag&drop. You could also use Microstation VBA to convert your design objects into WKT strings and export to CSV. Or you import the DGN file in AutoCAD(LT)/BricsCAD(Lite) and save it as DXF for later use in QGIS.

There are multiple options that are really much lighter than ODA.

Answer (score 0):

According to [GDAL documentation](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/oda.html#vector-oda), "These libraries are not publicly available. You have to became a member to get access to the libraries."
Once you have the libraries, you have to compile them and then GDAL with them.

I've just registered for a 60 days trial, will report here if I succeed in compiling and using GDAL with ODA platform, also on Windows.